# Flask HTTPS - Unable to upload a flask server with SSL(using waitress and nginx)

Tags: python, nginx, flask, ssl, waitress

I edited my question:

I was trying to change my flask server to a production-level server.
Unfortunately, I am failing at the moment to do so even with the example flask app:
When trying to connect without HTTPS the site works fine, when connecting with HTTPS I get a "This site can't be reached" error.

My nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate path/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key path/key.pem;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
 location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 5000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

After edditing my config i used this command in order for nginx to recognize the new config:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

My flask app:

```
from flask import Flask
from waitress import serve
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'> A very simple flask server !</h1>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
    logger = logging.getLogger('waitress')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    serve(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, url_scheme='https')
```

**Thanks a lot in advance for all your help!**

Comment: In the nginx configuration, I believe you're going to need to use either `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem(actually this was how I implemented it originally...).

Comment: Sure, I don't know if that's the only issue. So please tell us if you're running into another issue after that.

Comment: Sorry :\ I sent my comment to early accidentally and it seemed like your answer resolved my issue(which it didn't)...

Comment: No problem. Is there the same error message?

Comment: Yes, same error

Comment: @mor2778, did you ever figure this out? Please answer your own question if you did.